# Emulating a @hotmail.fr email address

Tags: facebook

I have a big issue here. A friend of mine has lost access to his facebook account and want to recover it.

Unfortunately, he used a `@hotmail.fr` email address as its security address and cannot receive any instructions to recover his password since `@hotmail.fr` are now deleted and forbidden by Microsoft.

Any idea on how I could help him? I have thought about emulating the `@hotmail.fr` address somehow - but never did that before!

Comment: Microsoft still own the domain. There is nothing you can do to emulate the domain.

Comment: @WizKid What can I do? Any idea please ?

Comment: Unless you plan on performing a large scale DNS hack that will affect half the internet, there is nothing to “emulate”.

Comment: If two-step verification was enabled for the hotmail account, maybe something like this can somehow help, https://www.express.co.uk/life-style/science-technology/1103427/hotmail-login-how-to-access-recover-old-hotmail-account-check-last-login-safe

Comment: Thanks @CBroe... I'm checking the link. This might be my best shot !